# JavaFX layout alignment, equivalent to GridBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm wondering if anyone has much experience with JavaFX 8. I'm doing some form layouts and need to align them (i'm abit OCD with this stuff). I know in Swing I could use GridBagLayout, but this isn't applicable anymore, where I could set weights and what not, but I don't think I can do that with GridPane, is there any equivalent to this in JavaFX?

I can't post images, so I've linked it, to what it looks like at the moment, and highlighted some areas that aren't what I want.

https://gyazo.com/c112ab623ffd66e6f723eb9be1fcaea9

The code is also available before

```
    public class ControlsPanel extends GridPane {
    private TextField[] buttons;
    private TextField[] miscTextFields;

    private Label[] labels;

    private Button startSimBtn;

    private TabPane tabPane;
    private Tab cooperatorTab, defectorTab;
    private final int PADDING = 5;
    private final String[] v = 
        {
            "C_A_N", "C_A_PD", 
            "C_A_PN", "C_N_N", 
            "C_N_PD", "C_N_PN", 
            "D_A_N", "D_A_PD",
            "D_A_PN", "D_N_N",
            "D_N_PD", "D_N_PN"
        };
    private final String[] miscTfLabelValues = 
    {
            "Apology cost: ", "Noise level: ", "Punishmment Cost: ", "Punished Cost: "
    };

    public ControlsPanel() 
    {
        buttons = new TextField[12];
        labels = new Label[buttons.length];
        miscTextFields = new TextField[miscTfLabelValues.length];

        for(int k = 0; k < miscTfLabelValues.length; k++) 
        {
            miscTextFields[k] = new TextField();
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) 
        {
            buttons[j] = new TextField();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new Label(v[i]);
        }

        tabPane = new TabPane();
        startSimBtn = new Button("Start");

        cooperatorTab = new Tab("Cooperator");
        defectorTab = new Tab("Defector");

        layoutComponents();
    }

    private void layoutComponents() 
    {
        setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        cooperatorTab.setContent(layoutCooperatorTab());
        cooperatorTab.setClosable(false);
        defectorTab.setContent(layoutDefectorTab());
        defectorTab.setClosable(false);

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(cooperatorTab, defectorTab);

        getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(Values.SCREEN_WIDTH));

        add(tabPane, 0, 0);

        add(layoutMiscPane(), 0, 1);
    }

    private GridPane layoutMiscPane() 
    {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();

        pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(PADDING,PADDING,PADDING, 15));


        pane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 75, 15, 15));
        pane.add(new Label(miscTfLabelValues[0]), 0, 1);

        pane.add(miscTextFields[0], 1, 1);

        pane.setPadding(new Insets(0, -100, 0, 0));
        pane.add(new Label(miscTfLabelValues[1]), 0, 2);

        pane.add(miscTextFields[1], 1, 2);

        //
        pane.add(new Label(miscTfLabelValues[2]), 0, 3);

        pane.add(miscTextFields[2], 1, 3);

        //
        pane.add(new Label(miscTfLabelValues[3]), 0, 4);

        pane.add(miscTextFields[3], 1, 4);

        return pane;

    }
    private GridPane layoutCooperatorTab()
    {

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();

        pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(PADDING,PADDING,PADDING, 15));

        pane.add(labels[0], 0, 1);

        pane.add(buttons[0], 1, 1);

        pane.add(labels[1], 0, 2);

        pane.add(buttons[1], 1, 2);

        //
        pane.add(labels[2], 0, 3);

        pane.add(buttons[2], 1, 3);

        //
        pane.add(labels[3], 0, 4);

        pane.add(buttons[3], 1, 4);


        //
        pane.add(labels[4], 0, 5);

        pane.add(buttons[4], 1, 5);

        //
        pane.add(labels[5], 0, 6);

        pane.add(buttons[5], 1, 6);

        return pane;
    }
    private GridPane layoutDefectorTab() 
    {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();

        pane.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(PADDING,PADDING,PADDING,15));

        pane.add(labels[6], 0, 1);

        pane.add(buttons[6], 1, 1);

        pane.add(labels[7], 0, 2);

        pane.add(buttons[7], 1, 2);

        //
        pane.add(labels[8], 0, 3);

        pane.add(buttons[8], 1, 3);

        //
        pane.add(labels[9], 0, 4);

        pane.add(buttons[9], 1, 4);


        //
        pane.add(labels[10], 0, 5);

        pane.add(buttons[10], 1, 5);

        //
        pane.add(labels[11], 0, 6);

        pane.add(buttons[11], 1, 6);

        return pane;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GridPane` is indeed the closest equivalent in JavaFX to Swing's `GridBagLayout`. You get a lot of control over the allocation of space to columns and rows by using `ColumnConstraints` and `RowConstraints` objects. These can allocate absolute min/pref/max sizes (width for columns and height for rows), or can allocate a percentage of the total width/height. You can also allocate priorities for growing, if the `GridPane` grows larger than the preferred size, and alignment properties for if a cell contains more space than its node uses.

Additionally, there are static methods in `GridPane` that can set properties on nodes; this allows for controlling alignment and grow priorities on a node-by-node basis, and also allows you to specify margins for each node.

For example, in your `layoutMiscPane()` method, you might do

```
ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
leftCol.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
ColumnConstraints rightCol = new ColumnConstraints();
rightCol.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
rightCol.setfillWidth(true);

pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, rightCol);
```

See the [documentation for `GridPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) and also for [`ColumnConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) and [`RowConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to style all of these by applying the correct css to them.

```
textfield.getStyleClass().add("mystyle");
```

This way you can add alignment, font weight, etc.